# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0. Searched in the following locations android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0. Searched in the following locations android app.
>    file:/C:/Users/malik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-database/16.0.0/firebase-database-16.0.0.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/malik/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-database/16.0.0/firebase-database-16.0.0.jar

**my app depenencies :**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'

implementation 'com.adityak:browsemyfiles:1.7'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try `Clean->Build`.

Comment: check internet connection. Also add `google()` in repositories.

Comment: Did you enable "Offline mode"? You can disable this by opening up the preferences dialog, then click on "Build, Execution, Deployment", then click on "Gradle", then uncheck "Offline work" (if it's enabled). Alternatively, you can search for "Offline work" in the searchbar of the preferences dialog.

Comment: Thanks everyone I got the solution by updating all firebase libraries to the latest available ....